# Want to get website's like box to link with fan page instead of websites administrative intereface?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

I am trying to link a like box on website to facebook fan page.

http://witheri.com

I created an APP (developer.facebook.com), went to settings -> advanced -> add page to create a fan page for a band. Then I used this open graph like button (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) to link page.

It is working on website, but when I click like, it creates a 3rd page, an insight page, with this message "This is the administration interface for your webpage at http://witheri.com. You can see Insights and publish to the users that have liked your webpage. Only the administrators of the webpage can view this interface, other users are sent to the webpage."

This is all fine, but I want the likes to appear on the fan page instead of the insight page. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That message explains the situation; the people who use the Like button are liking  http://witheri.com , the page you see on Facebook.com is only visible to you, and lets you see the insights for who likes the page, and lets you post things which will appear in the fans' news feeds